# zsh returns bad interpreter after Catalina upgrade

Tags: ruby, macos-catalina

I am getting an error message after upgrading to macOS Catalina.

> zsh: /usr/local/bin/colorls: bad interpreter: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby: no such file or directory

It seems Ruby has been updated since, when I run `ruby -v`, it outputs the following.

> ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]

How can I make colorls use Ruby 2.6 instead of Ruby 2.3 that was present when the command was installed?

I tried reinstalling and then uninstalling it multiple times, but I am still getting the same error.

I did manage to temporarily make the error message disappear using the following line.

```
PATH="`ruby -e 'puts Gem.user_dir'`/bin:$PATH"
```

Every time I open a new terminal, the error message comes again. I will like to find a way to make it persistent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After couple of different solutions I tried I managed to make it work with RVM.

Install rvm from terminal:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Once installation is complete, it will say something like:

```
To start using RVM you need to run `source /Users/{username}/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
```

So copy/paste that into terminal, and then install ruby version you want, I used:

```
rvm install 2.6.5
```

Now when you have your ruby in place you should be able to install gems for the version you've chosen, eg I installed bundler

```
gem install bundler
```

This will make rvm as default ruby manager, and will use 2.6.5 from terminal.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Definitely way to go. It works

Comment: Kinda worked, did tons of stuff but eventually fixed it somehow

Answer (score 5):

For me the version of the ruby installed with Catalina was newer. I only had to reinstall the missing gems so if you already have ruby installed, this might fix it:

`gem install colorls`

Answer (score 2):

[Here's what helped me](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8955#issuecomment-539267256):

```
brew install cocoapods --build-from-source
```

then:

```
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, christian Martin, but none of these options worked for me. 
My solution is - reinstalling `color ls` 
github pg —> https://github.com/athityakumar/colorls